# offline interactive OpenStreetMap in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

How to display a OpenStreetMap on a ui-form in Qt? In the main window of mainwindow.ui. I need an interactive map. The transmitting latitude, longitude of the point and adding information about the point.

How to make this example interactive and display on the mainwindow.ui form?

main.cpp :

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc,argv);
    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///places_map.qml")));
    view.setWidth(360);
    view.setHeight(640);
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

places_map.qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtPositioning 5.5
import QtLocation 5.6
//! [Imports]

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent

    //! [Initialize Plugin]
    Plugin {
        id: myPlugin
        name: "osm" // "mapboxgl", "esri", ...
        //specify plugin parameters if necessary
        //PluginParameter {...}
        //PluginParameter {...}
        //...
    }
    //! [Initialize Plugin]

    //! [Current Location]
    PositionSource {
        id: positionSource
        property variant lastSearchPosition: locationOslo
        active: true
        updateInterval: 120000 // 2 mins
        onPositionChanged:  {
            var currentPosition = positionSource.position.coordinate
            map.center = currentPosition
            var distance = currentPosition.distanceTo(lastSearchPosition)
            if (distance > 500) {
                // 500m from last performed pizza search
                lastSearchPosition = currentPosition
                searchModel.searchArea = QtPositioning.circle(currentPosition)
                searchModel.update()
            }
        }
    }
    //! [Current Location]

    //! [PlaceSearchModel]
    property variant locationOslo: QtPositioning.coordinate( 59.93, 10.76)

    PlaceSearchModel {
        id: searchModel

        plugin: myPlugin

        searchTerm: "Pizza"
        searchArea: QtPositioning.circle(locationOslo)

        Component.onCompleted: update()
    }
    //! [PlaceSearchModel]

    //! [Places MapItemView]
    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: myPlugin;
        center: locationOslo
        zoomLevel: 13

        MapItemView {
            model: searchModel
            delegate: MapQuickItem {
                coordinate: place.location.coordinate

                anchorPoint.x: image.width * 0.5
                anchorPoint.y: image.height

                sourceItem: Column {
                    Image { id: image; source: "marker.png" }
                    Text { text: title; font.bold: true }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //! [Places MapItemView]

    Connections {
        target: searchModel
        onStatusChanged: {
            if (searchModel.status == PlaceSearchModel.Error)
                console.log(searchModel.errorString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you planning for dynamic mapping of your map container to the view?

Comment: @Mohammad Kanan Yes.

Comment: Now I realized you are talking of Geographical map :). sorry I have no clue .. you need rich knowledge of QPainter ..QImage ...etc.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov do you want the .qml to be shown in your .ui or something similar to it?

Comment: @eyllanesc  Yes, is it possible to do this?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov check in Qt Designer if you have QQuickWidget

Comment: @IvanTriumphov you got it?

Comment: @ eyllanesc I do not quite understand what needs to be done.

Comment: @ eyllanesc I'm working in Qt Creator / Why do I need Qt Designer?

Comment: QtDesigner is the tool you use in Qt Creator to modify the .ui, so I ask you if you have it.

Comment: @ eyllanesc I have QtDesigner.  How do I check if I have a QQuickWidget?  I'm new, so I apologize for my misunderstanding.

Comment: On the left side are the widget, and there is a filter, put the name and check if you have it.

Comment: @ eyllanesc Yes there is this

Comment: @IvanTriumphov I have posted an answer, use the first method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least there are 2 ways using QtDesigner

**1. using the QQuickWidget plugin from Qt Designer**

Qt Designer is the tool used by QtCreator to modify the .ui, so it has more used widgets plugins, in my case I have it as shown below

[image]

and you go to the view of properties and in source you place the url of the .qml as it shows the following image:

[image]

Then we add to the .pro:

```
QT += quickwidgets
```

---

**2. If you do not have it, we can use the widget and promote it as a class that inherits from `QQuickWidget`**

for this we create a class that inherits from QQuickWidget:

```
#ifndef QUICKWIDGET_H
#define QUICKWIDGET_H

#include <QQuickWidget>

class QuickWidget: public QQuickWidget
{
public:
    QuickWidget(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR):QQuickWidget(parent){
        setSource(QUrl("qrc:/places_map.qml"));
        setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
    }
};

#endif // QUICKWIDGET_H
```

Then we drag the QtDesigner `Widget`

[image]

and we right click selecting `Promote to...`, after that we obtain a menu where we place the values shown in the image, press the `add` button and then the `promote` button:

[image]

Then we add to the .pro:

```
QT += quickwidgets
```

Both examples are in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/48251004)

Comment: Thank you so much . Is there an example of maps with a grid? Latitude and longitude, by right click would be transmitted to "Line Edit".

Comment: okay, I'll modify those examples so you see but it's similar to qml with c ++

Comment: Quite probably it is similar to qml with c ++, but I now can display ui.qml in ui. Will an example be added here? https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48251004

Comment: I have updated the first example with that functionality, in this case I have passed the QLineEdit to QML since QLineEdit inherits from QObject and has as property to text